# data:text/plain in new window not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, window, plaintext

I'm trying to open a new window with plain text data in Internet Explorer. The following javascript code works on Chrome and Firefox but not IE.

```
var text_data = "blahblah";
var data = "data:text/plain," + encodeURIComponent(text_data);
var myWindow = window.open(data, "_blank");
myWindow.focus();
```

I've tested on Internet Explorer 11. Why does this not work on IE? How can I get it to work for Chrome, Firefox AND Internet Explorer.

Thank you.